# How to publish Laravel project on Debian server when routs are not found?

Tags: php, laravel

I have developed a `Laravel` project and it's working fine on my localhost. I'm going to publish it on a server with `Debian` OS. I've defined a virtual host as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost     
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Payment/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/Payment>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my web.php:

```
Route::get('/','mainController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/payment','paymentController@payment')->name('payment');
```

There is a problem that /payment is not found and returns `The requested URL /payment was not found on this server` (404) error. What is the resean?

Also, I ran `php artisan route:list` and both routes are defined.

Comment: @Sumithran This topic does not answer my question.

Comment: Your virtualhost is missing server name, And you didn't provide the full info of your setup what kind of php are you using? what's your php handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your config file for Apache sites to direct your project directory root to the Laravel `public` directory.

Replace `<Directory /var/www/html/Payment>` with `<Directory /var/www/html/Payment/public>`

Comment: It also seems as if you are missing server name in your config.
If that doesn't solve it, follow as here: https://gist.github.com/dj1020/e9898200d82ad9a56c84e3cec644b44b